# How to use the wire cutter tool?

Tags: thief

How do you use the wire cutter tool?  I use Focus and see the wires, but when I approach them, there's no prompt to cut them.  I figured they'd work the same as the wrench, which gets used automatically when you approach a grate or other object that requires that tool and interact with it.  I also see wire junction boxes near the traps, however when I approach them nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, user misunderstanding on this.  I guess I haven't actually gotten to a trap that requires the wire cutters, I've only encountered pressure plates which are disabled by following their wires to a switch to disable them.  Sometimes this switch is nearby, other times it is a distance away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Use Focus to follow the wires for pressure plates, trunks, safes, etc.  They'll sometimes lead you to a panel and when you interact with it, the wire cutters are automatically used to snip a wire and disable all of the traps attached to it.  In some cases, this panel is several rooms away from the traps.  The first one I encountered like this was in Oxheart Perry's residence for the *Silence is Golden* quest.